# How to delete employees rows having less salary than avg salary, in Oracle ?

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

Hey I want to delete all the employee records having salary less than avg salary in oracle.What is the correct way to do so and how should I go for it ?

Comment: can you give more information like table structure and columns?

Comment: Say table consist of only two columns (emp_id, salary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from tableEmp where columnSal < (select avg(columnSal) from tableEmp)
```

Comment: Hey don't you think that as we go through the avg value will change.We're deleting the records for the table and it will change the avg value for the next record....

Comment: Can you tell me what will be the flow of execution for the query ?

Comment: @omjego Try it and find out... but this does work. The average is only calculated once and then is compared to all rows.